# Why I am getting WindowLeaked when trying to show dialog inside a custom class?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create an `AlertDialog`, I have done this hundred of times but this time it is not working. I have this code on my `onResume()` method in my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (DEBUG)
        Log.i("BrazoRobot", "onResume()");
    isSystemRdy = false;

    mBluetoothHelper = new BluetoothHelper(this, bluetoothName);
    mBluetoothHelper.connect();
    mBluetoothHelper.setOnBluetoothConnected(this);
}
```

The object `BluetoothHelper` which is not an Activity class is correctly created and I am passing the activity context to it:

```
public BluetoothHelper (final Context ctx, final String bluetoothName) {
    mActivity = ((Activity)ctx);
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.bluetoothName = bluetoothName;
}
```

The problem is on the `connect()` method where I am creating the dialog:

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    AlertDialog.Builder mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    mDialog.setTitle(ctx.getString(R.string.BTRequestTitle));
    mDialog.setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.BTRequestSummary));
    mDialog.setPositiveButton(ctx.getString(R.string.Yes), new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (DEBUG)
                Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Turning on Bluetooth...");
            mBluetoothAdapter.enable();     // Enciendo el Bluetooth
        }
    });
    mDialog.setNegativeButton(ctx.getString(R.string.No), new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (DEBUG)
                Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Exit");
            mActivity.finish();
        }
    });
    mDialog.show();
}
```

I am getting the following exception at `mDialog.show()`. `ctx` is the activity context I passed in the constructor, I also tried passing `mActivity` which is `((Activity) ctx)` to `AlertDialog.Builder` but I get the same exception.

The dialog is to ask user to enable Bluetooth. I know the correct way to do it is using the Built-In method calling startActivityForResult() but I want to have everything inside my custom class and I can't have onActivityResult() on my class if it isn't an Activity, that's why I am doing it on this way.

Why is this happening? AFAIK I am creating the dialog on the UI thread. I also tried creating the dialog in `onCreate()` method but it is still the same.

```
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411): Activity com.roboticarm.andres.BrazoRobot has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4130de20 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-495,244} that was originally added here
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.roboticarm.andres.BrazoRobot has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4130de20 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-495,244} that was originally added here
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at com.bluetoothutils.andres.BluetoothHelper.connect(BluetoothHelper.java:119)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at com.roboticarm.andres.BrazoRobot.onResume(BrazoRobot.java:247)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5217)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2862)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2901)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5204)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
03-06 21:06:20.320: E/WindowManager(31411):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

**EDIT 1 (onWindowFocusChanged)**

Tried this code as suggested:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus){
        // Conecto al dispositivo bluetooth
        mBluetoothHelper = new BluetoothHelper(this, "linvor");
        mBluetoothHelper.connect();
        if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Interface");
        mBluetoothHelper.setOnNewBluetoothDataReceived(this);
        setPreferences();

        // Indico que entro en el Analizador lógico
        mBluetoothHelper.write(logicAnalyzerMode);
    }
}
```

But I keep getting exactly the same error.

---

**EDIT 2 (Activity test)**

I have tried creating a Dialog in onCreate() and onResume() in an Activity and it is created perfectly with this simple code:

```
    public class CustomDialog extends Activity{

        private static final boolean DEBUG = true;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            AlertDialog.Builder mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            mDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.BTRequestTitle));
            mDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.BTRequestSummary));

            mDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.Yes), new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Turning on Bluetooth...");
                }
            });
            mDialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.No), new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Exit");
                }
            });
            mDialog.show();
        }
    }

But, if I put this code inside my class method called from my Activity I get the exception.
```

---

**EDIT 3 (Strange Fact)**

This is my connect() method where I get the exception when I call it from my Activity and the Dialog is shown:

```
public void connect (){
        // Compruebo que el dispositivo tenga Bluetooth
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Si no hay Bluetooth en el dispositivo muestro un dialogo alertando al usuario y salgo de la Activity
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
            dialog.setTitle(ctx.getString(R.string.NoBTAlertTitle));
            dialog.setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.NoBTAlertText));
            dialog.setPositiveButton(ctx.getString(R.string.Ok), new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mActivity.finish(); // Cierro porque no existe un módulo Bluetooth
                }
            });
        }
        // Si el dispositivo tiene Bluetooth me conecto
        else{
            // Compruebo que el Bluetooth esté activado, sino pido al usuario que lo active
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

                //mActivity.startActivity(new Intent(mActivity, CustomDialog.class));

                AlertDialog.Builder mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                mDialog.setTitle(ctx.getString(R.string.BTRequestTitle));
                mDialog.setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.BTRequestSummary));

                mDialog.setPositiveButton(ctx.getString(R.string.Yes), new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Turning on Bluetooth...");
                        mBluetoothAdapter.enable();     // Enciendo el Bluetooth
                    }
                });
                mDialog.setNegativeButton(ctx.getString(R.string.No), new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Exit");
                        mActivity.finish();
                    }
                });
                mDialog.show();
            }
            // Compruebo si el dispositivo no esta en los dispositivos emparejados (paired)
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                // Loop a travez de los dispositivos emparejados (paired)
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                    if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Name: " + device.getName() + " -- Address:  " + device.getAddress());
                    // Si el dispositivo coincide con el que busco lo asigno
                    if(device.getName().equals(bluetoothName)){
                        mBluetoothDevice = device;
                        // Establezco una conexión Bluetooth para enviar datos
                        establishConnection();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Sino salgo, debe estar en los dispositivos emparejados
            else{
                mActivity.finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

But if I create a separated method and call from the Activity also, I don't get the exception when the Dialog is shown:

```
public void dialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    mDialog.setTitle(ctx.getString(R.string.BTRequestTitle));
    mDialog.setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.BTRequestSummary));

    mDialog.setPositiveButton(ctx.getString(R.string.Yes), new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Turning on Bluetooth...");
        }
    });
    mDialog.setNegativeButton(ctx.getString(R.string.No), new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Exit");
            mActivity.finish();
        }
    });
    mDialog.show();
}
```

And use it:

```
mCustomClass.dialog();      // Dialog is shown, no exception
```

Comment: I'm sorry. My answer about `onWindowFocusChanged()` was wrong. I deleted it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after resting a little bit I solved it. My fault once more. The problem was basically that I was showing up the dialog and before it is showed I finished the Activity:

```
public void connect (){
        // Compruebo que el dispositivo tenga Bluetooth
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Si no hay Bluetooth en el dispositivo muestro un dialogo alertando al usuario y salgo de la Activity
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
            dialog.setTitle(ctx.getString(R.string.NoBTAlertTitle));
            dialog.setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.NoBTAlertText));
            dialog.setPositiveButton(ctx.getString(R.string.Ok), new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mActivity.finish(); // Cierro porque no existe un módulo Bluetooth
                }
            });
        }
        // Si el dispositivo tiene Bluetooth me conecto
        else{
            // Compruebo que el Bluetooth esté activado, sino pido al usuario que lo active
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

                //mActivity.startActivity(new Intent(mActivity, CustomDialog.class));

                AlertDialog.Builder mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                mDialog.setTitle(ctx.getString(R.string.BTRequestTitle));
                mDialog.setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.BTRequestSummary));

                mDialog.setPositiveButton(ctx.getString(R.string.Yes), new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Turning on Bluetooth...");
                        mBluetoothAdapter.enable();     // Enciendo el Bluetooth
                    }
                });
                mDialog.setNegativeButton(ctx.getString(R.string.No), new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Exit");
                        mActivity.finish();
                    }
                });
                mDialog.show();
            }
            // Compruebo si el dispositivo no esta en los dispositivos emparejados (paired)
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                // Loop a travez de los dispositivos emparejados (paired)
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                    if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Name: " + device.getName() + " -- Address:  " + device.getAddress());
                    // Si el dispositivo coincide con el que busco lo asigno
                    if(device.getName().equals(bluetoothName)){
                        mBluetoothDevice = device;
                        // Establezco una conexión Bluetooth para enviar datos
                        establishConnection();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Sino salgo, debe estar en los dispositivos emparejados
            else{
                mActivity.finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

I show the dialog on ´mDialog.show()´ but Bluetooth is still not enabled until I press the Ok button so there are no paired devices so I finish the Activity, but the dialog is still being drawed so I get the exception. Stupid error I know, I should take a rest sometimes.

So the ´connect()´ method is now:

```
public void connect (){
    if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "connect()...");
    // Compruebo que el dispositivo tenga Bluetooth
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Si no hay Bluetooth en el dispositivo muestro un dialogo alertando al usuario y salgo de la Activity
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
        dialog.setTitle(ctx.getString(R.string.NoBTAlertTitle));
        dialog.setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.NoBTAlertText));
        dialog.setPositiveButton(ctx.getString(R.string.Ok), new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "No bluetooth on device");
                mActivity.finish(); // Cierro porque no existe un módulo Bluetooth
            }
        });
    }
    // Si el dispositivo tiene Bluetooth me conecto
    else{
        // Compruebo que el Bluetooth esté activado, sino pido al usuario que lo active
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
            mDialog.setTitle(ctx.getString(R.string.BTRequestTitle));
            mDialog.setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.BTRequestSummary));

            mDialog.setPositiveButton(ctx.getString(R.string.Yes), new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Turning on Bluetooth...");
                    mBluetoothAdapter.enable();     // Enciendo el Bluetooth

                    // Espero a que encienda el Bluetooth
                    while(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled());

                    // Compruebo si el dispositivo no esta en los dispositivos emparejados (paired)
                    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                        // Loop a travez de los dispositivos emparejados (paired)
                        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                            if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Name: " + device.getName() + " -- Address:  " + device.getAddress());
                            // Si el dispositivo coincide con el que busco lo asigno
                            if(device.getName().equals(bluetoothName)){
                                mBluetoothDevice = device;
                                // Establezco una conexión Bluetooth para enviar datos
                                establishConnection();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // Sino salgo, debe estar en los dispositivos emparejados
                    else{
                        if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Finish Activity not in paired devices");
                        mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
                        mActivity.finish();
                    }
                }
            });

            mDialog.setNegativeButton(ctx.getString(R.string.No), new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(DEBUG) Log.i("BrazoRobotBT", "Exit");
                    mActivity.finish();
                }
            });

            mDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

And it is working properly and as expected. Thank you very much Waqas for your help but I don't have ´mDialog.dismiss()´ method on AlertDialog.Builder because it is automatically done.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid this error, you should call `mDialog.dismiss()` in the **onStop** method of your activity.

Reason: because you can't simply finish the dialog owner activity or jump to a new one without properly disposing the dialog window.

Comment: But the dialog is not being created in my Activity, it is created in my custom class inside connect() method, and the Activity is being closed because I am getting the exception, not because I am not dismissing the dialog when I exit the Activity.

Comment: dialogs are always created on top of an activity and to support this argument you are already providing activity's context to it. read my edited answer.

Comment: Bue I can't dismiss my dialog if I haven't even created it. My custom class is not an Activity class, just a class that connects to Bluetooth and there I want to create the dialog to ask user to enable Bluetooth. Hope you can understand me.

Comment: First of all, you don't need to create your own pop-up to ask the user to enable bluetooth, because you may use the existing bluetooth enabling activity from framework `startActivityForResult(new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE), return_code);` to get this done. Second, you need to check in **onStop** that if your dialog object is not null and its in visible state then dismiss it, e.g. `if(diag != null && diag.isShowing()){ diag.dismiss(); }`